# Waiting for table level lock on wordpress site

Tags: mysql, wordpress

We are experiencing issues with mySQL loading 100% of the server's CPU. While checking the running processes we found many of the following:

```
Waiting for table level lock | SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes'
```

The table is configured to MyISAM.

Any suggestion of how to optimize mysql?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and added an index to wp_option.option_name

Answer (score 0):

Converting engine to row level lock will prevent this issue. You may change to InnoDB
`ALTER TABLE 'wp_options' ENGINE=INNODB;`
Hope it helps for you

Comment: As this is a part of WordPress, could this change cause issues? (I don't know wnough about WordPress to know one way or the other; just a concern when your DB is part of a vendor offering.

Comment: Hi @RDFozz. Thank you for your question. Wordpress using default engine configured in my.cnf. You can see it here [https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/schema.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/schema.php). Engine for schema creation is not specified. It is looks like when he initially installed Wordpress default engine was MyISAM and maybe some migration to newer version of mysql was happened where InnoDB by default. Now is default engine is InnoDB. So, vendor in not offering tables engine and it is ok to change engine.

Comment: But better to dump table content before any schema changes of course :) `CREATE TABLE wp_options_temp LIKE wp_options;` `INSERT INTO wp_options_temp SELECT * FROM wp_options;`